# Lost an AirPod. Can I buy a replacement AirPod (used) and pair it which the one I still have?

Tags: airpods

I lost right side AirPod. Can I buy single right side AirPod?

Company name infinity.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different.  What is the company name here and how is it relevant? Do you need help selecting your model of airpod?